# Auto-brightening images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb, brightness

I found this code for auto-brightening images to an optimum level.

```
% AUTOBRIGHTNESS  
%        -->Automatically adjusts brightness of images to optimum level.
%    e.g. autobrightness('Sunset.jpg','Output.jpg')

function autobrightness(input_img,output_img)
my_limit = 0.5;
input_image=imread(input_img);
if size(input_image,3)==3 
    a=rgb2ntsc(input_image);
else     
    a=double(input_image)./255;
end
mean_adjustment = my_limit-mean(mean(a(:,:,1)));
a(:,:,1) = a(:,:,1) + mean_adjustment*(1-a(:,:,1));
if size(input_image,3)==3    
    a=ntsc2rgb(a);
end
imwrite(uint8(a.*255),output_img);
```

1. I want to ask, why the value of `my_limit` is 0.5?
2. How we determine that value?
3. Why use the 'ntsc' colorspace instead of another colorspace like hsv, lab or yCbCr?

Comment: These are things you should ask the author of the code. I agree with you that NTSC (“Never The Same Color”) is an odd choice.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to ask, why the value of my_limit is 0.5? How we determine that
>   value?

The color space NTSC ranges from 0 to 1 for each of its channel. So essentially 0.5 is the center. This is equivalent of choosing 127 for RGB space

> Why use the 'ntsc' colorspace instead of another colorspace like hsv,
>   lab or yCbCr?

I believe ntsc provides 100% coverage of the color space and so the author of the code choose it. However most modern systems wont display in this color space and hence we use standard RGB for display. I used this website to come to this conclusion [NTSC color space](https://www.noteloop.com/kit/display/color-space/ntsc-1953/)

Also, as pointed by  Cris in this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTSC) page. NTSC stores  Luminance and Chrominance and the author of the code is adjusting the Lumiance(brightness). I am including a modified script I used to come to these conclusions

```
input_img='lena_std.tif'
output_img='lena2.tif'
my_limit = 0.5;
input_image=imread(input_img);
if size(input_image,3)==3 
    a=rgb2ntsc(input_image);
    k=rgb2ntsc(input_image);
else     
    a=double(input_image)./255;
end
mean_adjustment = my_limit-mean(mean(a(:,:,1)));
a(:,:,1) = a(:,:,1) + mean_adjustment*(1-a(:,:,1));
if size(input_image,3)==3    
    a=ntsc2rgb(a);
end
imwrite(uint8(a.*255),output_img);
output=uint8(a.*255);
imwrite(uint8(k.*255),'test.tif');
ntscoutput=uint8(k.*255);
```

Comment: I modified the answer based on the section of wikipedia you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: what the meaning this code?
size(input_image,3)==3 ?

Comment: It makes sure the image has three components per pixel which is true in case of NTSC

Comment: Example: luminance_mean = 0,06; 0,109; 0,196; 0,322; 0,483.

And i want luminance_mean for all of images is 0,196.

Comment: I tried change my_limit = 0.196, but it doesnt work. Can you help me?